# Java regex to accept either UUID or only numbers in URL pattern

Tags: java, regex, spring-boot, spring-security

I am adding multiple http security in spring boot and adding filters based on the URL pattern.I have an endpoint /abc/{id} which accept query param as id which can either be UUID or numbers.i am trying to create a regex pattern which can accept either UUID or only numbers something like http.regexpattern(“/abc/“).authorzerequest(). I tried with pipe operator (OR in regex) but it is not working here.
I dont want to add two different http security configuration one for uuid and other for numbers.
What can be the regex pattern which can work in http?
Here is the code with regex OR operator(Pipe |) which is not working"

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.regexMatcher("/abc/([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12})|([0-9]+$)").authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().addFilterBefore(new CustomFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.addFilterAfter(new EnvironmentFilter(jwtTokenUtility), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

}

Comment: Can you share your code with some sample strings with actual vs expected outcome?

Comment: I figured it out. Not sure how spring is interpreting pattern but it is working by reverting the pattern around OR operator `http.regexMatcher("/abc/([0-9]+$)|([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12})").authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated().and().addFilterBefore(new CustomFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether Spring has it's own regex flavor, but if you can find out what flavor of regex it is, you can use https://regex101.com/ which is a very good testing environment for regular expressions.

Not knowing Spring, Java has it's own Regex-flavor, which contains the pipe operator as OR and which works well, to my knowledge. To give you an example:

```
// example input
String input0 = "MyPatteRn"; // matches
String input1 = "myPattern"; // matches
String input2 = "MypaTTern"; // no match

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("my|My(Patt|PaTT)e(?:r|R)n");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputSequence);
if (matcher.matched()) {
    String patt = matcher.group(1);
}
```